# Weyl's Lemma Proof

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

[image]
[image]

I have managed to show that we have a subsequence converges to a function $\bar{u}$ on any compact subsets and it agrees with $u$ a.e. I have some trouble extending the argument to show that $u$ is smooth. More precisely, $u$ agrees with a smooth function a.e. I am wondering if anyone could help me with that?

I thought $\bar{u}$ depends on $\Omega.$ Maybe I was thinking somethign wrong.

I have made another attempt to solve this problem:

[image]

Comment: You have shown that $u=\bar{u} \in C^\infty$ a.e., hence $\bar{u}$ is a smooth representative of $u$, hence $u$ is smooth. Does this clear things up for you?

Comment: I still feel like there is something I needed to say that the continuous reprentation is 'the same' in some sense for every compact subset. I have made another attempt. I am wondering if the solution makes sense to you?

Comment: I think you are on the right track but I also think there is an easier way to show that. For every point $x \in D$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ small enough such that the closed ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ is contained in $D$. For instance choose $2\epsilon = dist(x,\partial D)$. But $u = \bar{u}$ on this ball, hence, u is smooth everywhere.

Comment: If $u=\bar{u}$ a.e. on the ball,  I do not think it imply u is smooth everythere. By definition, u is an equivalence class of function in $L^1$. If we remove a set of measure 0, then we can say this u is smooth. If we choose two closed ball in U, Arzela-Ascoli only tells us that we have two subsequences converge uniformly, it does not tell us any additional information about the limit on these two closed balls.

Comment: Yeah but there can be only one continuous representative, thus, they are the same.